# Unity and .NET Framework versions

Tags: .net

I am looking to use an IOC container in my current project which is in .NET 2.0. Can anyone tell me what framework versions does 'Unity' work with, does it require .NET 3.5? I looked at the MS documentation and couldn't find anything about supported .NET versions.

Regards,
ilias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the **[System Requirements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203104.aspx)**:

> The following are the minimum system requirements for Unity:
>
> ...
>
> - Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0, 3.0,
>   3.5, or 3.5 SP1